# Qt: Switching 'virtual desktops' on linux makes the multimediawidgets/videographicsitem example, stop displaying the video

Tags: qt, video, virtual-desktop

If you've got the Qt 5.12.8 (the version that ships with Ubuntu 20.04) examples installed + built, start playing a video with it, switch virtual desktops and the video stops (you can't hear it). Come back, and the widget is white, in some sense it forgot the video. The example's 'brother', `multimediawidgets/videowidget`, works as you'd expect: start playing a video, go to another virtual desktop, you can hear it still playing, come back, and it's carried on as you'd expect. Interestingly, if you first *pause* the video in the `videographicsitem` example, do the switch-and-back, the video correctly still shows and is resumable when you come back, so, it's just if you switch while playing. I presume it's a bug - can anyone think of a workaround? Thanks.

edit: This is the same for Qt 5.15.2, the latest Qt 5.x as I write. As for Qt 6.2.x (latest as I write), it didn't have that example - I've read that totally new versions of Qt take a while to get the multimedia stuff.

Comment: Most probably yet another Qt bug, try switching to latest version; but before that, search for how to relayout (to refresh views), trigger that by button click to test, if that helps, make it automated (on screen resize event).

Comment: Yes, it's still in the latest Qt 5. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it.